# Coupled differential equation in wolfram cloud

Tags: differential-equations

`NDSolve[{r1'[t]==-r1[t]b[t]-r2[t]d[t]-r3[t]c[t],r2'[t]==r1[t]d[t]+r2[t]b[t],r3'[t]==2a[t]+r1[t]c[t]-2r3[t]b[t],
x1'[t]==-x1[t]b[t]-x2[t]d[t]-x3[t]c[t],x2'[t]==x1[t]d[t]+x2[t]b[t],x3'[t]==x1[t]c[t]-2x3[t]b[t],
y1'[t]==-y1[t]b[t]-y2[t]d[t]-y3[t]c[t],y2'[t]==y1[t]d[t]+y2[t]b[t],y3'[t]==y1[t]c[t]-2y3[t]b[t],
z1'[t]==-z1[t]b[t]-z2[t]d[t]-z3[t]c[t],z2'[t]==z1[t]d[t]+z2[t]b[t],z3'[t]==z1[t]c[t]-2z3[t]b[t]
},{r1[t],r2[t],r3[t],x1[t],x2[t],x3[t],y1[t],y2[t],y3[t],z1[t],z2[t],z3[t]},t]`

I have this coupled differential equation and because of degree of freedom I know that it is solvable but wolfram cloud give an undetermined error . How could I handle it¿

Comment: few things. You have more dependent variables than equations, second, with numerical solver need to give also initial conditions, third, with numerical solver need to tell it the range of time `t`. If you fix these, then you can try again.

Comment: Yes I have more dependent variable but it is solvable analyticly. With Dsolve is the same result.@Nasser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a linear system that can be arranged as

$$
\dot X = A\cdot X
$$

Calling

```
X = {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], y1[t], y2[t], y3[t], z1[t], z2[t], z3[t]};

equs = {
 r1'[t] == -r1[t] b[t] - r2[t] d[t] - r3[t] c[t],
 r2'[t] == r1[t] d[t] + r2[t] b[t],
 r3'[t] == 2 a[t] + r1[t] c[t] - 2 r3[t] b[t],
 x1'[t] == -x1[t] b[t] - x2[t] d[t] - x3[t] c[t],
 x2'[t] == x1[t] d[t] + x2[t] b[t],
 x3'[t] == x1[t] c[t] - 2 x3[t] b[t],
 y1'[t] == -y1[t] b[t] - y2[t] d[t] - y3[t] c[t],
 y2'[t] == y1[t] d[t] + y2[t] b[t],
 y3'[t] == y1[t] c[t] - 2 y3[t] b[t],
 z1'[t] == -z1[t] b[t] - z2[t] d[t] - z3[t] c[t],
 z2'[t] == z1[t] d[t] + z2[t] b[t],
 z3'[t] == z1[t] c[t] - 2 z3[t] b[t]};

 A = Grad[Map[Last, equs], X];
```

so if b[t], c[t], d[t] are constant, the system

```
DSolve[D[X, t] == A.X, X, t]]
```

can be obtained closed form. In the general case with b[t], c[t], d[t] variables t dependent, no closed form. To solve this last case we need to give b[t], c[t], d[t] plus initial/boundary conditions in cond, and then proceed with

```
NDSolve[{D[X, t] == A.X, cond}, X, {t, 0, tmax}]]
```